# bootstrap carousel strange behaviour with first slide being blank and 2 clicks to activate nav

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel, jsfiddle

I am using the bootstrap demo from there website.

But when I am using it with my mark up, a blank slide appears first. There mark up is taken from my source and I cannot find anything wrong with it. I put the source into a fiddle and the same thing happens.

How can this be happening why my mark up is identical the demo.

Please see this fiddle to experience the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/aVBUy/3/

This is my mark up...

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

    <div class="carousel-inner">

        <div class="item" style="background-image: url('riders-carousel-011.jpg');">
            <img src="wp/wp-content/themes/riders-experience/images/x.gif" alt="" />
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>Riders for Health</h1>
                    <p class="lead">Riders Experience Africa is more than just a holiday&#8230;
It is a unique chance to see the work of Riders for Health and to learn about how motorcycles are helping&hellip;</p>
                    <a class="btn btn-large btn" href="riders-for-health/">Veiw more information</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item" style="background-image: url('riders-carousel-02.jpg');">
            <img src="wp/wp-content/themes/riders-experience/images/x.gif" alt="" />
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>Rider Check List</h1>
                    <p class="lead">Motorcycle helmet Full face or open face. A motocross or enduro style helmet is a better choice. These are specifically designed for off-road use and have particular&hellip;</p>
                    <a class="btn btn-large btn" href="rider-check-list/">Veiw more information</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>

</div>
```

Help would be great as i'm going a little mad. I've done exactly as the demo shows (i hope)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to initialize it first with `$('..').carousel()` in jquery, or just add class "active" to the first item..

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/skelly/aVBUy/5/

Comment: Because I am using wordpress I am struggling to add an active class to first looped item. So I try and call it with $('..').carousel() alone but does not work - http://jsfiddle.net/aVBUy/6/

Comment: dont worry did this... `class="item <?php $c++; if ( $c == 1 ) echo 'active'; ?>"` and got the active class in :-) thanks very much.